# Is there a way to get DSI output on RPi Zero W?

Tags: display, pi-zero-w, dsi

I'm trying to make an inexpensive smartphone, So I don't want to buy a really expensive small HDMI display, so... DSI. But the pi zero doesn't have DSI output . I've looked into hdmi to DSI adapters and they're very scarce, I've also googled if I could solder a DSI out on, but nothing came up. If you guys could help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is a DSI adapter?
All Pi models (except the Pi Zero) support the [Raspberry Pi Touch Display](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/README.md) which connects through the DSI connector. There is no common standard for this interface.

Comment: Get a 3A+ is has DSI & CSI.